# Django URL custom parameters on Base Class View

Tags: django, class, url, view

I have writen class-based views based on `generic.base.view` to get information about users profiles (the data is comming from different models and db tables). The views will be used for viewing some user information on a social network and also by the own user on edditing his own profile.

Here is the view:

```
class ProfileView(PageTitleMixin, generic.View):
    template = "common/profile.html"
    template_name = "Perfil"
    page_title = _('Profile')
    active_tab = 'profile'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('usrxtnsion:profile')

    def get_queryset(self):
        return User.objects.filter(username=self.kwargs['username'])

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        ctx = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        account_info = Profile.objects.get(pk=self.request.user.profile.pk)
        user_info = User.objects.get(pk=self.request.user.pk)
        ctx['user_fields'] = self.get_profile_fields(self.request.user)
        ctx['profile_fields'] = user_info.profile_set.all()
        ctx['address_fields'] = user_info.useraddress_set.all()
        ctx['account_fields'] = account_info.account_set.all()
        ctx['username'] = self.request.user.username
        return ctx

    def get_profile_fields(self, user):
        field_data = []

        # Check for custom user model
        for field_name in User._meta.additional_fields:
            field_data.append(
                self.get_model_field_data(user, field_name))

        # Check for profile class
        profile_class = get_profile_class()
        if profile_class:
            try:
                profile = profile_class.objects.get(user=user)
            except ObjectDoesNotExist:
                profile = profile_class(user=user)

            field_names = [f.name for f in profile._meta.local_fields]
            for field_name in field_names:
                if field_name in ('user', 'id'):
                    continue
                field_data.append(
                    self.get_model_field_data(profile, field_name))

        return field_data

    def get_model_field_data(self, model_class, field_name):
        """
        Extract the verbose name and value for a model's field value
        """
        field = model_class._meta.get_field(field_name)
        if field.choices:
            value = getattr(model_class, 'get_%s_display' % field_name)()
        else:
            value = getattr(model_class, field_name)
        return {
            'name': getattr(field, 'verbose_name'),
            'value': value,
        }

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        user_form = SignupForm(instance=self.request.user)
        profile_form = ProfileForm(instance=self.request.user.profile)
        account_form = AccountForm(instance=self.request.user)
        address_form = UserAddressForm(instance=self.request.user)
        username = request.user.username

        return render(request, 'common/profile.html', {
            'user_form': user_form,
            'profile_form': profile_form,
            'account_form': account_form,
            'address_form': address_form,
            'username': username
        })

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        user_form = SignupForm(instance=self.request.user)
        profile_form = ProfileForm(instance=self.request.user.profile)
        account_form = AccountForm(instance=self.request.user)
        address_form = UserAddressForm(instance=self.request.user)

        if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid() and account_form.is_valid() and address_form.is_valid():
            user_form.save()
            profile_form.save()
            account_form.save()
            address_form.save()
            messages.success(request, _('Seu perfil foi atualizado!'))
            return redirect('settings:profile')
        else:
            messages.error(request, _('Por favor, corriga os erros abaixo.'))

    def form_valid(self, form):
        try:
            old_user = User.objects.get(id=self.request.user.id)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            old_user = None

        form.save()

        new_email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
        if new_email and old_user and new_email != old_user.email:
            ctx = {
                'user': self.request.user,
                'site': get_current_site(self.request),
                'reset_url': get_password_reset_url(old_user),
                'new_email': new_email,
            }
            msgs = CommunicationEventType.objects.get_and_render(
                code=self.communication_type_code, context=ctx)
            Dispatcher().dispatch_user_messages(old_user, msgs)

        messages.success(self.request, _("Profile updated"))
        return redirect(self.get_success_url())
```

The problem is that I'm trying to insert the user name on the url and I'm not getting into it. The URL is the following:

```
path('profile/<username>/', login_required(views.ProfileView.as_view()), name="profile"),
```

But i am having some problem to pass the argument `<username>` to the URL. I've already tried to insert the `get_queryset()` to get all the details of `username`, but Django still gives me the error msg

```
Reverse for 'profile' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['profile/(?P<username>[^/]+)/$']
```

I have read the docs about [generic class-based display views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/), the [general class-based views intro](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/class-based-views/) and the [`as_view()` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/class-based-views/base/#django.views.generic.base.View.as_view), with no success in finding a solution. I've also searched around in stackoverflow for some solution and I didn't find anything.

Any hints on how to make this work?

---

**EDIT**

The error occurs when i'm trying to access the login page:

[image: This is the error]

---

**EDIT 2**

My url patterns for this are the following:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(), {'template_name': 'common/login.html'}, name="login"),
    path('resetar-senha/', auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(), name="forgot_password"),
    path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(), {'next_page': ''}, name="logout"),
    path('change-password/', core_views.ChangePasswordView, name="change_pass"),
    path('profile/<str:username>/', login_required(views.ProfileView.as_view()), name="profile"),
    # path('dashboard/<username>/', views.DashboardView.dashboard, name="dashboard"),
    path('cadastrar/', core_views.SignupView, name="create_user")
]
```

I am using django built-in login view, with the following settings:

```
LOGIN_URL = "usrxtnsion:login"
LOGOUT_URL = "usrxtnsion:logout"
SIGNUP_REDIRECT_URL = "usrxtnsion:profile"
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = "usrxtnsion:profile"
```

Comment: You've posted a whole lot of code here, but you haven't said what is causing the problem. When do you get that error? Where is it that you are trying to generate the profile URL?

Comment: Hi Daniel! This error occurs when i'm accessing the login page, which redirects to profile.

Comment: So you need to show that code that does the redirect, rather than the profile view.

Comment: Hmm, I thought it could be done with get_queryset and I would not need another view to redirect the login page... Goin to look into it